# PHP SimpleXML Skipping First Element

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following SimpleXML code. When I print the output, it always seems to skip the first element. So in the example below, it skips the brands element and goes straight to websites. No matter how many sub-levels I have, it always skips the first one.

Is this normal? how can I fix this?

```
$xml = '
<brands>
<websites>
</websites>
</brands>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
echo "</pre>";
```

Example Output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [websites] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 

        )

)
```

Comment: isn't that because your xmlobject === root element, in other words, if you do `$xml->getName()` it should be `brands`

Comment: show output please

Comment: @raksaeng i've updated to show output

Comment: @DarkMukke add that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it using another element:

```
<root>
    <brands>
        <websites>
        </websites>
    </brands>
</root>
```

Comment: I would avoid using the tag `<xml>` in any production code - I believe it's officially reserved by the spec.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you for your watchfulness. Unfortunately, I did not know about it. The specification [says](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn) that `Names beginning with the string "xml", or with any string which would match (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')), are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.`

Comment: Actually, I've just re-read the question, and while this works, it's entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @IMSoP I think if it works, it does not mean that it is correct. In addition, we do not know how it will be used (perhaps the XML will be sent to a client, which strictly follows the specification). Therefore, I am grateful for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The root element is not being "skipped". In SimpleXML, there is no separate "document" object; instead, when you parse a file or string, the object you get back represents *the root element* (there is always exactly one, if it's valid XML).

You can confirm this by running `echo $xml->getName();`

In general, don't pay too much attention to what `print_r`/`var_dump`/etc show for a `SimpleXMLElement` object - much of the data is stored internally in a form that those functions can't see.